# unable to check username exists or not

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a registration program which insert username password into mysql database. I am now trying to check the username exixts or not. I wrote the following program. its not working. it showing "mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource."
I really need your expert suggestion

**registration.php**

```
<?php 
require 'jcon.php';
if(isset($_POST["username"], $_POST["firstname"],$_POST["password"])){
    $username=$_POST["username"];
    $firstname=$_POST["firstname"];
    $password=$_POST["password"];
}
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM member WHERE username='$username'");
if(mysql_num_rows($query) != 0)
{
echo "Username already exists";
}
else{
$sql="INSERT INTO member (username, firstname, password)
VALUES ('$username', '$firstname','$password')";}
if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "Dear {$firstname} ! you have been successfully registered. "
?>
```

Comment: don't mix `mysql_` and `mysqli_`.

Comment: did you check what `mysql_error()` is showing?

Comment: Change all instances of mysql to mysqli please. Also, it's saying expects parameter 1 to be resource because the query probably failed. Please also run the query in the db to see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it showing "mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource

This is the typical case where `mysql_query` returns `false` upon failure therefore triggering the infamous:

> mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource

This can be caused by multiple factors. Try running the query in phpMyAdmin or directly to the database and see the error or fetch the last mysql error via [`mysql_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php).

It's good practice to always check if the returned value of `mysql_query` is `false` or if the `mysql_error` string is not empty:

```
if ($result and empty(mysql_error()))
    // everything ok
```

*Note: Never ever mix `mysql_` and `mysqli_` functions. If you have to choose I'd go with `mysqli` since `mysql_*` functions are considered deprecated.*

Comment: I am absolutely newbie. Can you please edit the code and paste corrected code here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM member WHERE username = '$username'`.
```

If he's not registered, cnt column will return `0`.
Therefore, you can avoid the needed parameter as it is possible for `mysql_query` to return `FALSE` if the query doesn't reproduce result and it's not possible for `mysql_fetch` and *friends* to make it as parameter.

Comment: `mysql_query` [never](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) returns `NULL`.