# How to make a username entries required to be unique with php

Tags: php, mysql

So, I've got a register form that I want all the usernames (email adresses) have to be unique, I made it so the database entries have to be unique, but then the error that the user gets is my generic one (see $message), which I could change to another message, but then the user wouldn't know whether the account hasn't been created due to an error server side or a duplicate email address.

```
$message = 'Sorry there must have been an issue creating your account';
```

What I have been struggling to get is a way to have a custom error that says something like: "Sorry this email is already in use" when the username is already in use.

Below is the code for my register form  (i didnt make this)):

```
<?php

session_start();

if( isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ){
    header("Location: restricted.php");
}

require 'database.php';

$message = '';

if(!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['firstname']) && !empty($_POST['surname'])):

    // Enter the new user in the database
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (email, password, firstname, surname) VALUES (:email, :password, :firstname, :surname)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password', password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));
    $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $_POST['firstname']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':surname', $_POST['surname']);


    if( $stmt->execute() ):
    $message = 'Successfully created new user';
    else:
    $message = 'Sorry there must have been an issue creating your account';
    endif;

endif;

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Register</title>
    <?php include '../header.php'; ?>
</head>
<body>

    <?php if(!empty($message)): ?>
        <p><?= $message ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <h1>Register</h1>
    <span>or <a href="login.php">login here</a></span>

    <form action="register.php" method="POST">

        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email" name="email">
        <input type="password" placeholder="and password" name="password">
        <input type="password" placeholder="confirm password" name="confirm_password">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your first name" name="firstname">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your surname" name="surname">
        <input type="submit">

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Rather than just inserting and relying on "generic failure", try selecting to see if a user with that email exists.

Comment: If the email is unique, just do a select on it and see if it is already in the database before the insert then throws your personalized message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First run a `select` query to check if the username/email adress already exists.

If exists return a error, if not `insert` in database.
You should validate your `post` not only if it is empty. Also if the data is valid like correct email markup, password the same, username is unique etc

Comment: So i kinda new to php and trying to learn it, here is my attempt at doing it, which has inevitably failed :P, ill put my attempted code into a paste bin so it looks nicer, if you could edit my code/do you own so i can see where i messed up :) http://pastebin.com/1Akj2DQs . Inside of database.php is http://pastebin.com/yZ7UrsMe  its also giving the error of: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$query' (T_VARIABLE) in /dirremoved/register.php on line 25

Comment: Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17800354/check-if-username-exists-in-mysql-table-via-php
Or add me on skype: hetischris

Comment: Check your line 26(Pastebinline) your trying to where `email` is in `email`. You should use `users`. So: ` `$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email"``